# Solving $\iint \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{3/2}} dx dy $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This is a question in a book of statistics and  probability. To prove that this function is a Probability density function, we should solve it to get the answer equals to 1.
I haven't had to deal with these kinds of integrals for a while.
I need a level by level solution with complete description.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBtuH.jpg)

Comment: What space is the integral over? All of $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so maybe try polar coordinate change.

Comment: in range of all real numbers,

Comment: If range just one dimensional reals, how can one integrate using two variables?

Comment: as far as I know, first we should integrate it by considering y as a constant, then again integrate on y

Comment: Isn't that same as integration over 2-space?

Comment: I don't know :(

Comment: I havn't study math for more than 12 years, I totally forget them

Comment: I think this integral will be involved if polar coordinates not used. Suggest: Check a calc 2 book to see how the polar integral is set up.

Comment: ranges of x , y are in the picture I've already attached. Is it clear?

Comment: The attached picture you put up makes clear the space is 2-d (x,y plane). So using polar as in Jack's answer is the best way to go. As found there the integral isn't 1 so one has to divide the function by a constant to make it a density.

Comment: in the main problem, there is a coefficient ( $ \frac{1}{2\pi} $ ), that make it a density.
Thanks for your consideration

Answer (score 4):

$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\pi\frac{2 \rho}{(1+\rho^2)^{3/2}}\,d\rho=\pi\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}\right]_{0}^{+\infty}=\color{red}{2\pi}. $$

Comment: Thank you, Could you please describe it in detail?

Comment: @SRoshan: $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{3/2}}$ is a radial function and the length of $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=\rho^2\}$ is $2\pi \rho$, so the first equality is justified either by Cavalieri's principle or by the general formula giving an integral in polar coordinates. The second equality is just a consequence of the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
In the main problem, there is a coefficient ( $ \frac{1}{2\pi} $ ), that make it a density.